# Javascript onbeforeunload Issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have an issue with the following code. What happens is when a user closes their browser, it should prompt them to either click OK or click CANCEL to leave the page. Clicking OK would trigger a `window.location` to redirect to another page for user tracking (and yes, to avoid flame wars, there is a secondary system in place to assure accurate tracking, in the event of the user killing the browser from the task manager (as mentioned in similar questions)). CANCEL would remain on the page, the issue being that no matter what button you hit, you get redirected as if you wanted to leave the page. The relevant code is below.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    var where_to = confirm("Click OK to exit, Click CANCEL to stay.");
    if (where_to == true)
    {
        window.location="logout.php";
    }
    if (where_to == false){
        alert("Returning...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) doesn't work that way. The associated function should return a string which is in turn to be displayed on the default `onbeforeunload` dialog.

```
function confirmExit() {
    return "This message will appear in the dialog.";
}
```

But you aren't returning anything and taking it in your own hands with a `confirm()`. When the function doesn't return anything, then the `onbeforeunload` dialog won't be displayed at all.

To invoke the real logout, you'd like to use the [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) event. Here's a rewrite:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
window.onunload = logout;

function confirmExit() {
    return "Click OK to exit, Click CANCEL to stay.";
}

function logout() {
    window.location = 'logout.php';
}
```

You're however dependent on the webbrowser whether the last will *actually* hit the server. Most if not all of the webbrowsers don't. I'd rather fire an ajaxical request on that URL, but you're dependent on the webbrowser as well whether it will work flawlessly.

Comment: Ajax requests do not work. I mean, they do work, but sometimes they don't have enough time to complete before the page actually unloads. We've tried this technique on our development machine, and the only way to make sure that the request will be complete is by making it synchronous. Which causes really big problems with IE, because it has a limited stack of ajax requests per browser instance.

Comment: @Igor: fair point. I did another local tests again and it works on IE8 and Chrome, but not on FF3 and Safari4.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev you can achieve this without problem if the ajax call is a fire and forget. The call will hit the server, always.

Comment: @Anzeo, I don't remember already - it was very long ago, but I think that even "fire and forget" calls that we experimented with have worked about 50% of the time.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev stumbled upon this question while searching for a similar solution, fortunately our client has decided to accept ours, which is to show a warning message when the client's leaving the page without logging out :)

Comment: Will this work if the browser is closing due to OS shutdown?

Comment: @techie_28: depends on how OS shuts down. If it's shutdown because the PC caught fire, then well .. I'm not sure :)

Comment: @BalusC.. in case of a normal shutdown(Start Menu -> ShutDown button)?beforeunload is not fired in this case when browser close but does fire if closed using the cross (X) button.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of hijacking the user's browser you could fire an XHR request from inside your unbeforeunload() and get the data you need sent over to where you need it?

Without more of the use-case it's hard to tell, but this may provide a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in IE9 and Chrome

---

```
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
  if (elm.addEventListener) {
    elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
    return true;
  }
  else if (elm.attachEvent) {
    var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
    return r;
  }
  else {
    elm['on' + evType] = fn;
  }
}

function exitAlert(e) {
  var msg = "This message will appear in the dialog.";
  if (!e) { e = window.event; }
  if (e) { e.returnValue = msg; }
  return msg;
}

addEvent(window, 'beforeunload', exitAlert, false);
```